# Does completing a mission in Brutal difficulty counts towards the "Wings of Liberty: Hard 5/10/15/20/25" achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Thanks to those achievements being pretty glitched at the moment I didn't get the *"Wings of Liberty: Hard 5/10/15/20/25"* achievements by replaying missions on Hard difficulty after completing them in Normal difficulty.

I read that you have to restart a new Campaign and never change difficulty level throughout the whole play, which I am willing to do. But I wouldn't like to restart it twice (one time in Hard difficulty, and one in Brutal), so I am thinking of restarting it directly in Brutal difficulty.

Can anyone confirm that completing missions in Brutal difficulty not only counts towards the *"Wings of Liberty: Brutal 5/10/15/20/25"* and *"Liberty Completionist: Brutal"* achievements, but also towards the *"Wings of Liberty: Hard 5/10/15/20/25"* and *"Liberty Completionist: Hard"* ?

Comment: You are able to play brutal and still make the hard achievements? Man you are goood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Any achievement, *any* achievement, that has a difficulty requirement as part of the achievement can also be completed on a higher difficulty. This means that (if you're good enough) you can get all of the Wings of Liberty Mission achievements on a single playthrough.

E.g., for the Red Lobster achievement, you can taunt the Brutalisk into the lava on Normal, Hard, *or* Brutal -- you don't "have" to be on normal (despite the listing to the contrary)

Comment: I knew that for mission-related achievements, I wasn't so sure for the Story Mode achievements. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It does count indeed.

Comment: Because "yes" is less than 15 characters!